# JAVA does not work with the same resources on Netbeans Project and JAR file when the compile the code

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, resources, ram

When I build the Project and run the program on netbeans, it runs perfect and fast enough, yet when I export the jar file and start the program on that it is slow and stuck at the middle of the process.

I track the java resource usage and I found the memory problem.

How can I overcome this problem? I want to use the program same as on the Netbeans. How can I remove the constraint to resource usage of JAVA?

I am sorry, I forgot to tell I tried that. I think heap size is different than what I need. -Xmx and -Xms does not work. They don't change the java.exe or javaw.exe memory usage. I need what the Netbeans do to use more ram.

All pictures shows that the problem clearly.

Netbeans runs the program on java with more ram:

[image: Image ->]

When the process parse and write to excel started it use so much ram:

However, when I start the program on JAR file, process so slow and use limited ram:

At the end of the process (parse and write to excel) it was very slow and after a while it stuck because of the lack of memory space that java allows:

[image: Image ->]

Comment: Please include some of the code for your problem.

Comment: There is no problem with code, just the java memory usage limitations. I can not share the code on public, sorry.

Comment: Something in your code is either no bueno and not properly managed or you are just using a ton of resources. Without code probably won't get too much help.

Comment: @ŞEREFCANERYAVUZ the problem is that this question is likely to be closed without the actual code.

Comment: If it is possible I can share the code, but sharing company's data is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that memory limit is the only problem then set the maximum heap size that JVM can use, add -Xmx2G command line parameter to java.exe.
You can read more on -X options [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to tell I tried that. I think heap size is different than what I need. -Xmx and -Xms does not work. They don't change the java.exe or javaw.exe memory usage. I need what the Netbeans do to use more ram.

Comment: @ŞEREFCANERYAVUZ -Xmx *is* the option to provide a larger heap. If your memory usage does not change when using -Xmx then the parameter didn't take effect (maybe your particular way of running the VM replaces it, or it didn't get through), or your application *doesn't* make use of more memory because it has no need for it. Without any additional information nobody can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, but I don't know why JDK 1.8 block the memory usage?

Answer : http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=167390